# Would this be efficient? Factorials with JavaScript

Tags: arrays, math, push, reduce, factorial

Even though I am learning JavaScript, I came up with this solution for Factorials and I'd like to get some feedback.

```
function factorialize(num) {
var total= [];
  if(num!==0){
    for(var i=1; i<=num; i++){
      total.push(i);
    }
    var newTotal =  total.reduce(function(a,b){
      return a*b;
    });
    return newTotal;
  }else {
    return 1;
  }
}
console.log(factorialize(6));
```

This other way I found online is easy to read and understand, I just simply can't think this way.

Non-Recursively

```
var factorial = function(n) {
if(n == 0) {
    return 1
} else {
    product = 1;
    for(i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        product *= i;
    }
    return product;
  }
}
console.log(factorial(num));
```

Recursively:

```
var factorial = function(n) {
if(n == 0) {
    return 1
} else {
    return n * factorial(n - 1);
 }
}
console.log(factorial(num));
```

Comment: "I'd like to get some feedback" is too vague for this site. If you have a particular concern, tell us. If not, you may want to ask this question at the [Code Review site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: The first method is interesting; put the numbers in an array and then use the array.reduce method. It's going to be less efficient than simply multiplying as you go along. Mainly because of all the array access you need to do. The recursive method requires a lot of function calls so it less efficient than the simple loop. All methods are useful for introducing programming concepts, but not alway the most practical.

Comment: I also think I am wasting resources by using an array in the beginning. I just don't seem to have a simple approach such as the recursive or non-recursive solutions. Bummer!

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is reasonable, though what could be criticized about it, is that it is a bit wasteful with memory. The other versions only need to keep one intermediate value as state (assuming tail-call optimization for the recursive version), whereas your algorithm relies on an array of length n. You could use a generator instead of a list to avoid this.

Comment: Tail-Call ? - Are you referring to factorial(n - 1) ? When it's called within the function? I don't get that. I have been trying to learn JS and still can't approach problems like these the programmer's way.

Comment: This not only applies to javascript specifically. Naive recursion implementation impose a memory cost per call, which can be avoided by an optimization called tail-recursion. This requires the recursive call to be the last statement in the function, which is the case for the above recursive definition.